# How to use interfaces declared in an external JAR in a JSF application hosted in a local TomCat server

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, tomcat, jar

I have a JSF 2 application that depends on a external JAR file. Such a JAR file is generated by other project in the same Eclipse workingset. This architecture was chosen for the sake of modularity, so I have some domain core services in a JAR. My application depend on that JAR file and uses it in order to provide end user services.

In the JSF2 application I have a simple managed bean, as seen below:

```
package ufprJSF;

import java.util.Collection;

import javax.faces.bean.*;

import unidades.dominio.Cargo;
import unidades.dominio.repository.CargoRepository;

@ManagedBean
public class CargoBean {
    private CargoRepository cargoRepository;
    private Collection<Cargo> todos;

    public Collection<Cargo> getTodos() {
        return todos;
    }

    public String listarTodos() {
        return "cargos?faces-redirect=true";
    }
}
```

The home page of the application shows a menu that has some links, one of them linked to the `listarTodos()` method of the above presented bean. That method just redirects to another page of the application.

If I try to run the application in a local TomCat 8 server, I receive:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /ufprJSF/index.xhtml
type Status report

message /ufprJSF/index.xhtml
description The requested resource is not available.

Apache Tomcat/8.0.14
```

The `index.xhtml` **does not use** the above bean, it just shows a menu with a link to `listarTodos()` method of that bean. The console shows the following (among many other lines in the stack):

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: unidades.dominio.repository.CargoRepository
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1293)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1145)
    ... 33 more
```

The project compiles, so during the compile time, the referenced interface is found, what leads me to believe that the dependencies of the JSF2 application are correctly setup. The JAR that contains such a type shows under `Referenced Libraries` node in the Eclipse package explorer.

If I simply comment line 12 as below

```
...
@ManagedBean
public class CargoBean {
//      private CargoRepository cargoRepository;
    private Collection<Cargo> todos;
...
```

The runtime problem disapears. However, my bean depends on the `CargoRepository` interface to do what it has to do, so I have to find a way of using that JAR in my JSF2 application.

Any help on this issue will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does that jar exist in the deployed applications web-inf/lib directory, too?

Comment: @Stefan: not really, it´s simply referenced in the project to allow the use of the types declared in it. Are you telling me that TomCat will need them during runtime to resolve the references to those types?

Comment: For sure they are needed at runtime too.

Comment: @Stefan: thank you so much for your answer, it just fixed my problem! Nothing like talking to an expert. Please, add your suggestion as an answer and I will mark it as a solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the Jar library exists in the deployed applications WEB-INF/lib directory.